Why is my ActiveRecord query executing separately instead of as a single query?
I have the following ActiveRecord query in my Rails application:
Order.where(
  summary_id: Summary.where(
    association_table: Invoice.table_name,
    association_column: 'invoice_id',
    association_value: self.orders.ids
  ).select(:id),
  status: :pending
).find_each { |order| order.process }

When I run this in the Rails console, it generates a single SQL query:
SELECT orders.* FROM orders WHERE orders.summary_id IN (SELECT summaries.id FROM summaries WHERE summaries.association_table = 'invoices' AND summaries.association_column = 'invoice_id' AND summaries.association_value IN (?)) AND orders.status = 1

However, when I check the CloudWatch logs, I see that the query for Summary is executed first, followed by the query for Order. Is it normal for these queries to execute separately, rather than as a single combined query?
Any insights or recommendations on how to ensure they execute as a single query would be greatly appreciated!

.ids is shorthand for pluck(:id) and will create a separate query - I would say that ids is usually a code smell that indicates that you should be using a join or passing a relation that can be turned into a subquery. It's hard to fix your code since we need to see the schema, models and  what you actually expect the query to output. It looks to me like you're missing some assocations that could make this less messy.

Try  self.orders.select(:id) instead of self.orders.ids. That returns an ActiveRecord::Relation that can be lazily evaluated. The same thing you did between Order and Summary.
.ids executes a query and insert those values on the parent query.
